# NSInternalInconsistencyException mutating method sent to immutable object in xcode 6.1

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults, nsmutabledictionary

In My office We have two iMac that in the first Xcode 6.0.1 in second 6.1

We work in the same app and in 6.0.1 everything work fine and in 6.1 the app is Crashes.

I really hope I will explain the problem properly.

this is the Xcode output :

```
2014-11-03 10:48:57.358 appName[3282:505629] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray insertObject:atIndex:]: mutating method sent to immutable object'
*** First throw call stack: 

List item
...
```

my problem start from here when i clicked the send button :

```
-(void)sendButtonClicked
 {
NSMutableDictionary *pack = [self createMessagePack];
[Conversation addMessage:pack ToConversationWithUser:theUser];
[inputTextView setText:@""];
}
```

create pack:

```
-(NSMutableDictionary *)createMessagePack
{
NSMutableDictionary *msg = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[msg setObject:CurrentUser.UserName forKey:@"sender"];
[msg setObject:theUser.Number forKey:@"reciever"];
[msg setObject:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0] forKey:@"createdAt"];
[msg setObject:inputTextView.text forKey:@"text"];

return msg;
}
```

here tha app crashes in this line " [conversation addObject:message]; "

```
+(void)addMessage : (NSMutableDictionary *)message ToConversationWithUser : (appUsers *)user
{
NSMutableArray *conversation = [Conversation getConversationWithUser:user];
if ([conversation count] == 0)
{
    [user savePerson];
}
[conversation addObject:message];

[Conversation saveConversation:conversation WithUser:user];
}
```

Conversation getConversationWithUser:user jump to here

```
+(NSMutableArray *)getConversationWithUser : (appUsers *)user
{
NSMutableDictionary *allConversations = [Conversation getAllConversations];

NSMutableArray *theConversation = [allConversations objectForKey:user.appNumber];

if (!theConversation) // the conversation not exist yet..
{
    theConversation = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
}

return  theConversation;
}
```

[Conversation getAllConversations]; jump to here

```
+(NSMutableDictionary *)getAllConversations
{
NSMutableDictionary *allConversations = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"conversations"];
if (!allConversations)
{
    allConversations = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:allConversations forKey:@"conversations"];
}
return allConversations;
}
```

I understand that I have a problem with " NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults " that return immutable , But everything I tried from here still does not solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change :

```
NSMutableDictionary *allConversations = [Conversation getAllConversations];
```

to this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *allConversations = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[Conversation getAllConversations]];
```